# Form control change to runtime object VB.net

Tags: vb.net, controls

I have a form what contains about 10-15 `CheckedListBox` objects on a `Panel` named `PanelFilterBoxes`.
Each `CheckedListBox` can contains lots of items (1 to max ~2000).

I have to reload regulary the items of this controls based upon a datatable's column unique values (plus some extras).

Now I have a code like this (this below is just a shorten extract):

```
For c = 0 To PanelFilterBoxes.Controls.Count - 1
    '--get unique datas from datatable 
    Dim dtUnique() As String = ....

    '--change items of the control
    Dim contr As CheckedListBox = PanelFilterBoxes.Controls.Item(c)
    contr.Items.Clear()
    contr.Items.Add("*All", True)
    contr.Items.Add("*Search: ", False)

    For Each myValue As String In dtUnique
        '--add items with checked true
        contr.Items.Add(myValue, True)
    Next

Next
```

It is not so long, but takes some times. I'd like to try what if I create a runtime object (*I can put data in a runtime created object faster than a form object*), and "replace" the control on the form with this?

So my "big challenge" how can I do this?

I tried this ways, but not works :/

```
For c = 0 To PanelFilterBoxes.Controls.Count - 1
    '--get unique datas from datatable 
    Dim dtUnique() As String = ....

    '--change items of the control
    Dim contr As CheckedListBox = PanelFilterBoxes.Controls.Item(c)

    '--runtime temporary object
    Dim tempContr As new CheckedListBox

    contr.Items.Clear()

    tempContr .Items.Add("*All", True)
    tempContr .Items.Add("*Search: ", False)

    For Each myValue As String In dtUnique
        '--add items with checked true
        tempContr .Items.Add(myValue, True)
    Next

    '--1 - this doesn't works, but doesn't produce any error
    contr=tempContr

    '--2 - it works, but the items aren't checked
    contr.Items.AddRange(tempContr.Items)

Next
```

Anybody has a solution for this?

Thank you